# For $a,b \gt 0$, show that if $a^3 \gt b^3$ then $a \gt b$ (without using the difference of two cubes formula)

Tags: inequality

For $a,b \gt 0$, show that if $a^3 \gt b^3$ then $a \gt b$.

I can see that one approach is to use the formula for the difference of two cubes (coupled with a field property).

E.G.

$a^3 \gt b ^3 \implies a^3 - b^3 \in P$, where $P$ is the set of positive real numbers.

$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

$a^2+ab+b^2 \in P$, which means that $a-b$ must be as well.

**However**, I am hoping someone could provide a different method just so I can see how people play around with inequality proofs.

I tried to build a chain of inequalities to carry out a transitivity argument, but I am not having any luck.

Thank you  ~

Comment: $f(x) = x^3$ is strictly increasing, therefore its inverse function is strictly increasing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about proof by contradiction?

If $a\leq b, a^2\leq b^2, a^3\leq b^3$,which is contradictory to $a^3>b^3$, thus $a>b$.

Comment: +1 for sure! (but I am hoping for a direct/constructive argument if possible)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option from calculus:

For two numbers $x$ and $y$ where $x > y > 0,$ the fundamental theorem of calculus gives us that $x^{\frac{1}{3}} - y^{\frac{1}{3}} = \int_y^x \frac{d}{dt}t^{\frac{1}{3}} dt = \int_{[y,x]} \frac{1}{3}t^{-\frac{2}{3}} dt$. For any $t > 0$, $\frac{1}{3}t^{-\frac{2}{3}} > 0$, so $\int_{[y,x]} \frac{1}{3}t^{-\frac{2}{3}} dt > 0$.

Now let $x = a^3$, $y = b^3$, and we get that $a^3 > b^3 > 0$ implies $(a^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} - (b^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} = a - b > 0$.

Admittedly this is much less elegant than the proof by contradiction, but it is more direct as you asked.

Comment: With calculus, it might be easier to show that $x^3$ is strictly increasing by differentiating it.